# Are July and August bad months to release an iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, game-industry, release

After one year of indie game development I end my development cycle in summer time. I spoke recently with a marketing advisor and I was told me that I should never release something over the summer as everyone (especially in southern European countries) tends to go on holiday and not to read blogs/magazine etc..

I am not 100% sure about this as I personally would still read a tech magazine on the beach :).

Are there some statistics available on best time periods to release an iPhone game?

I am aware that many big companies tend to release games in the period between October/November but I can't afford waiting that long.

Comment: Likely too many variables to give a definitive answer. Depends on the game, the market, the advertising, etc. If you can't wait to release it, then do it. You'll never know if waiting would be better or not. Just make the most of the release you have. Someone might come out with the same game in the meantime or who knows what.

Answer (score 3):

Some companies target to release their titles **around Christmas**. Other companies target **[E3](http://www.e3expo.com/)**. There's a lot of buzz around E3 and it is coming soon. So it might be actually a good time to release in summer. And of course, when people go on holiday nowadays, they take their iPhones to the beach and they might just need something to play when they are sunbathing.

Edit:

1. you might want to read this article: [Mobile Development Lesson Learned: Ship Now!](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/05/31/mobile-development-lesson-learned-ship-now-guest-piece/)
2. [Not indie games, but big games are released every month](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2013/05/18/2013-video-game-release-schedule.aspx)
3. [XBOX market indie games sorted by release date, they are released all the time too...](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Games/XboxIndieGames?SortBy=ReleaseDate)

Comment: I agree with the beach thing.. and also it could be an advantage not having to compete with the big companies. I am wondering if there are some stats somewhere on indie developers release dates or variation of number readers of tech blogs/websites in the months of July/August. I should pheraphs email Wired.com with this question :)

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a link to a relevant article.

Comment: You're talking about big name companies.  E3 has companies like SEGA and Bethesda and Ubisoft and Warner Bros.  "Shall I take the booth next to CAPCOM??"  "YES PLEASE!!  We'll push SQUARE ENIX off to that other area in the back."

Answer (score 2):

No month is a bad time to release a game, if the game is good.

It is more important to not release at the same time of competing games, such as releasing your clone of Angry Birds at the exact same time as a AAA release like Angry Birds 2: The New Birds.

Pay attention to what is going on, and release when the game is ready to release and you feel people will notice your game. Pay attention to what popular blogs and game sites are discussing, as releasing during a media dry spell can be great for publicity.

Comment: Always take a look at your direct competition. If you've got less hype going on than Angry Birds 2: The New Birds, wait for them to release. A very nice thing can happen in the meantime: Angry Birds 2 can be received by the users as utter crap - then is the time to make your product shine the most. Otherwise, wait for Angry Birds 2 to cool down a bit.

Comment: Great advice from Alex M.

Answer (score 1):

"Releases" or "launches" only make sense (and those conventional rules only apply) *if a lot of people are expecting your product*.  I notice AAA developers and large studios releasing games around just before Christmas (such as Mario Bros Wii and Mario Kart) so that might matter (because these games do make a great Christmas gift).

But if nobody's ever heard of you or your company, then you're releasing it into a very big place with a lot of things (other apps) already moving around and taking up space.  You can hope your app catches on by word of mouth or by advertising yourself, but it doesn't matter *when* you release it.  I think there is just too much going on for that kind of thing to *matter* - what really matters is how good your app is.  You won't fail *because* you released in August.